# JavaScript website vulnerability

Tags: javascript, php, html

this morning I noticed a possible vulnerability on my web site; I'm not sure at all if my site can be damaged with it but well...

On my site I use a JavaScript code to open(display) different sections (other pages) inside the main page;

On the main index.php I've this code where the other pages are displayed:

In the head:

```
<?php
$section = "default";
if (isset($_GET["page"]))
{
  $section = $_GET["page"];
}
?>
```

In the Body:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    openPage('<?php echo($page); ?>');
</script>
```

And the JavaScript function is this one:

```
function openPage(page, form)
{
var data = "page=" + page;
if (form != null)
    data += "&" + $("#" + form).serialize();

$("#content").html("<center>Wait..</center>");
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "content.php",
    data: data,
    success: function(result) {
        $("#content").html(result);
    }
})
}
```

The content.php

```
<?
  if (file_exists("pages/".$page.".php"))
    include("pages/".$page.".php");
  else
  {
    include("pages/default.php");
  }
?>
```

My problem is that if I write in the url:

```
url.com/index.php?page=</script><script>alert(1)</script>
```

An alert message appear, what I could do? Is this dangerous? How I can fix it?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not JS vulnerability, this is your code vulnerability.

You can use htmlspecialchars:

```
<?php
$section = "default";
if (isset($_GET["page"]))
{
  $section = htmlspecialchars($_GET["page"]);
}
?>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlspecialchars.asp

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is dangerous as people with malicious intent can now form URLs executing client side code on your domain. This can range from showing a simple alert box to hijacking cookies. This is called [cross-site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Ignoring whether your current setup is a good one, you can fix your vulnerability by [sanitizing](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42498/which-is-the-best-way-to-sanitize-user-input-in-php) the `$_GET['page']` variable before outputting it:

```
htmlspecialchars($_GET['page']);
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer!